# Can a SKProductsRequestDelegate receive a response for a random transaction?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

If I place a payment into the queue...

```
public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {

    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}
```

... normally, the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` will receive a call back regarding this payment. Can it also receive a call back for a transaction from, say, a previous usage of the app?

In other words, does my `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` need to be able to handle a transaction that I'm expecting *and* any other transactions, which may still need to complete, even though the user may not be directly concerned with them at that moment?

Comment: Two words: "restore purchases".

Comment: I'm only using consumables.

Comment: I guess you may receive a call for a purchase that was initiated previously, but somehow didn't go through (e.g. there was some kind of network delay, and then your app was terminated), so you'll receive it later and in an unrelated context. Probably not a very common occurence, but with users on cellular networks that's a possibility.

Comment: Cool. That's what I figured because I think I've read people saying that call backs happen as soon as an app starts.